# Convert byte string to bytes or bytearray

Tags: python, byte, arrays

I have a string as follows:

```
  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'
```

How can I convert this to an array of bytes? ... and back to a string from the bytes?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

in python 3:

```
>>> a=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'
>>> b = list(a)
>>> b
[0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 128, 0, 3]
>>> c = bytes(b)
>>> c
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'
>>>
```

Comment: I just realized that `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'` is iterable. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful: using lists `b = list(a)` allows doing (by mistake) `b[5] = 1550`, because b **is not** an array of bytes. However, if  `b = bytearray(a)` , then `b[5] = 1550` gives an error, because 1550 is not a byte.

Comment: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 15):

From string to array of bytes:

```
a = bytearray.fromhex('00 00 00 00 07 80 00 03')
```

or

```
a = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03')
```

and back to string:

```
key = ''.join(chr(x) for x in a)
```

Comment: So I need to replace `\x` with a space first?

Comment: No, just  a = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03')