# How to convert (bytes string) to bytes in Python 3?

Tags: python

How can I convert

```
(type["str"])" b' ' "
```

to

```
(type["bytes"],len =16)b' '
```

in `python3`

For example:
I want to convert

```
"b'\xf5\xd9\xfc\x8b\x05W\xa5"\xcad\xb6\x15\xc5\xba?\xfe'"
```

to

```
b'\xf5\xd9\xfc\x8b\x05W\xa5"\xcad\xb6\x15\xc5\xba?\xfe'
```

How can I do?

Comment: This question may have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310695/convert-byte-string-to-bytes-or-bytearray)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3) SO question.

Comment: I have tried it. He will return my array of one word. This needs to be a byte itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert byte string to bytes or bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310695/convert-byte-string-to-bytes-or-bytearray)

Comment: My list has no way to convert to utf8 because he has been encrypted
He will return that I can't convert utf8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: if your input string is the representation of a byte string (with leading `b` and string quotes), you can use the `eval` function

Comment: Oh, that's ok, thank you Aemyl.